# Significados jurídicos de "interesar" y "deducir"

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, lenguaje-jurídico

> "... **intereso** que la sala **deduzca** testimonio de particulares por delito de falso testimonio al juzgado de guardia."

Llevo un par de días dándole vueltas a esta frase.
Ninguno de los significados de [**interesar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=LtrPccN) me cuadra con el uso *"intereso **que** (alguien haga algo)"*, y ninguno de los significados de [**deducir**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=C0u0Q9o) me cuadra con el uso *"(alguien) deduzca (algo) **al** juzgado"*.

¿Algún abogado o jurista podría explicar la manera en que se están usando estos verbos aquí?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construyendo sobre la base de la [respuesta de ukemi](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28871) aquí y los [comentarios de blonfu](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46061?m=49569998#49569998) en el chat, junto con mi propia investigación, he podido comprender el uso que se hace de estos verbos.

- **Interesar**: en lenguaje jurídico se utiliza simplemente como fórmula para **pedir a la sala que lleve a cabo algo**, como por ejemplo la desestimación de un caso o la apertura de una causa paralela.
  Se pueden encontrar multitud de ejemplos en actas de juicios buscando por [`"intereso a la sala"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22intereso%20a%20la%20sala%22) o por [`"intereso que se desestime"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22intereso%20que%20se%20desestime%22) (y alguno por [`"intereso a su Señoría"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22intereso%20a%20su%20se%C3%B1or%C3%ADa%22), aunque desconozco si correcto o no), en los que se puede ver que el uso es siempre ese, el de "solicitar". A pesar de lo que diga el DLE, no he encontrado pruebas de que a día de hoy se use en el sentido de "recabar de alguien".
- **Deducir testimonio de particulares**: es una fórmula jurídica con un significado bastante concreto. Por una parte, **"deducir testimonio"** significa ***«sacar de los autos originales una [copia testimoniada](https://www.uned-derecho.com/index.php?topic=117776.0) y remitirla al Juzgado competente cuando se estime que se ha podido cometer un delito en la causa»*** ([fuente](http://opositoajusticia.foroactivo.com/t291-que-quiere-decir-deducir-testimonio)). No quiere decir eliminar un testimonio de un testigo, ni sacarlo del sumario, ni nada relacionado con "restar, descontar" ni con "sacar una conclusión" que son las acepciones que recoge el DLE. Además, **"testimonio de particulares"** es otro [término jurídico específico](http://www.enciclopedia-juridica.biz14.com/d/testimonio-de-particulares/testimonio-de-particulares.htm) que no tiene nada que ver con "particular" en el sentido de "persona", sino que se refiere, más o menos, a un procedimiento por el cual se sacan ***«copias fehacientes de determinados documentos obrantes en otros autos judiciales»***.

Teniendo en cuenta todo lo anterior, y **usando un lenguaje más llano, lo que dijo el fiscal fue**:

> Solicito a la sala que se saquen copias fehacientes de los autos del juicio y se envíen al juzgado de guardia para investigar un posible delito de falso testimonio.

Answer (score 7):

*Deducir* aquí se usa con el sentido de "Restar o descontar...", como ["strike from the record"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strike_from_the_record) se suela usar en cortes americanos. Esta ambigüedad se evita en inglés en que los dos sentidos tienen dos verbos distintos: *deduce* y *deduct*.

*Interesar* se usa con el sentido de “solicitar o recabar de alguien...”: <sup>[1](https://rebeccajowers.com/2018/02/22/use-of-interesar-in-legal-texts/) [2](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/interesar-legal.1065542/)</sup>

> Rather than “to manifest interest” as the term is sometimes rendered, in legal contexts *interesar* often has the meaning of *solicitar* (to request, to petition, to motion, etc.), especially when used in pleadings and other court documents. As defined in the DLE, “interesar may mean *“solicitar o recabar de alguien, datos, noticias, resoluciones, etc.”*

Comment: Perdon, pero no entiendo la confusión (posiblemente por qué no soy nativo, y traducido a inglés es sintacticamente igual) - *[intereso que] la sala`_subjeto` deduzca`_verbo` testimonio [de particulares]`_objeto-directo`*.